# Getting error undefined offset -1 in PDF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I am trying to generate PDFs in Laravel using mpdf library some pdfs are working fine but in some pdfs i am getting an error

> message: "Undefined offset: -1", exception: "ErrorException",…}
> exception: "ErrorException" file:
> "/var/www/html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Tag/BlockTag.php" line: 118
> message: "Undefined offset: -1" trace: [{file:
> "/var/www/html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Tag/BlockTag.php", line: 118,
> function: "handleError",…},…]

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $courtName = $request->name;
        $id = $request->id;
        
        $data = ModelName::functionName($id); 
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.secondary-PDF', compact('data',$data));
        return $pdf->download('my.pdf');
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex)
    {
        return $ex->getMessage();

    }    
}
```

above code i am using to generate PDFs. I am getting this error only in some PDFs not all. Please help me with this.

Below is my view code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{$data->FileName}}</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


</head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    @page {
    header: page-header;
    footer: page-footer;
}

@page{
    header:page-header;
    margin-top:105t;
}

@page{
    footer:page-footer;
    margin-top: 50pt;
}

</style>

<body>

    <htmlpageheader name="page-header">
        <p style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">{{$data->FileName}}</p>
    </htmlpageheader>
    <br>
    @if(!Session::has('UserId'))
    <htmlpagefooter name="page-footer">
        <div style="border-top: 1px solid #000;">
          <img style="margin-top:10px;" height="30" width="90" src="{{asset('images/lq-logo.png')}}" alt="footer">
          <p style="margin-left: 450px; margin-top:-30px; color:#000; font-size: 13px;"><b>Printed For: {{ date("d-m-Y",strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())) }} On: {{date('h:i:A')}}</b></p>
        </div>
    </htmlpagefooter>
    @else
    <htmlpagefooter name="page-footer">
        <div style="border-top: 1px solid #000;">
           <img style="margin-top:10px;" height="30" wdth="90" src="{{asset('images/lq-logo.png')}}" alt="footer">
           <p style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top:-30px; color:#000; font-size: 13px;"><b>Printed For: {{Session::get('UserName')}}&nbsp;{{ date("d-m-Y",strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())) }} On: {{date('h:i:A')}}</b></p>
        <div>
    </htmlpagefooter>
    @endif
    

    <div style="text-align: justify;"> 
          {!! $data->Content !!}
    </div><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that this error is happening in your view. The array will be empty in some views but not all, that's probably why for some PDF's you are getting this error, and for some you are not.

Comment: Can you include your view file?

Comment: this error is for your view file. put your view code

Comment: okay i am adding my view file. But for which i am getting this error  has data.

Comment: This should be fixed in mPDF, create a bug report at mPDF's github.